# How to extract a filename from a URL & some extra data attached to it?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, url

I'm trying to extract the filename from a download URL that not only end with the filename itself but an extra data is attached to the URL after the filename
https://some_website.com/folder/file_name.mkv?st=OyvPiQZL8HmbCkapHo-tLg&e=1571543844

I tried using the os.path.basename in python.
It includes the filename and the extra content itself 
like the above link return

file_name.mkv?st=OyvPiQZL8HmbCkapHo-tLg&e=1571543844

instead of

file_name.mkv

Comment: So is the goal to use a query parameter as a file name? Can you post code, sample input, current output, and expected output? Also please use markdown in questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
[^/]+(?=\?st)
```

might work OK.

#### Test

```
import re
string = ' https://some_website.com/folder/file_name.mkv?st=OyvPiQZL8HmbCkapHo-tLg&e=1571543844'
expression = r'[^/]+(?=\?st)'

print(re.search(expression, string).group(0))
```

#### Output

```
file_name.mkv
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/c4Swbj/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/c4Swbj/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

```
urld = 'https://ragex.eu/home.html?lol=sdasd'
returned_data = urld[urld.rfind('/') + 1: len(urld)]
print(returned_data) #output : home.html?lol=sdasd
```

Well, I am no expert but here's a much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using a combination of urlparse and os

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

url = "https://some_website.com/folder/file_name.mkv?st=OyvPiQZL8HmbCkapHo-tLg&e=1571543844"

os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)

output >> 'file_name.mkv'
```